# What were the first DEX on Ethereum and why does not the SEC investigate Uniswap?

Tags: uniswap, etherdelta, decentralized-exchange

I'm doing some history on the rise of DEXes and wanted to get an idea of what was the first DEX on Ethereum or some other blockchain. I know that Etherdelta was one of the first DEX back in the day, but they got stopped by the SEC. My question now is why doesn't the SEC stop Uniswap as its also accessed via a website and its headquarters is in Brooklyn NYC.

Comment: You are incorrect, the first DEX was on Ripple, couple of years before EtherDelta: https://capitalgram.com/posts/history-of-cryptocurrencies/

Answer (score 0):

> My question now is why doesn't the SEC stop Uniswap as its also accessed via a website and its headquarters is in Brooklyn NYC.

Only the SEC can answer to this question, as their investigations are not public.

I suggest you call the SEC and ask.

Comment: I guess here is your answer https://www.wsj.com/articles/regulators-investigate-crypto-exchange-developer-uniswap-labs-11630666800